# check if variable is of type array in fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid

Is it possible in fluid to check if the type of a variable is an array? I search for something like this.

```
<f:if condition='{myvar.Type == "Array"}'></f:if>
```

Or do I have to create my own ViewHelper for this purpose?

Comment: What is the usecase? Such logic does not belong in the template.

Comment: I need to check if a variable is of type array before i pass it to my partial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by writing my own ViewHelper

```
class TestViewHelper extends AbstractViewHelper 
{
    /**
    * Arguments Initialization
    */
    public function initializeArguments()
    {
        $this->registerArgument('myvar', 'string', 'test', TRUE);
    }

    /**
    * @return integer test
    */
    public function render() 
    {

        $arg      = $this->arguments['myvar'];
        $argType  = gettype($arg);
​
        if (preg_match("/array/i", "$argType")) {
            return 1;    //match
        } else {
            return 0;    //No match
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
{namespace mynamespace=YOUR_EXTENSION_NAME\YOUR_VENDOR_NAME\ViewHelpers}

<f:if condition="<mynamespace:isarray myvar='{_all}'/>==1">
    <f:then>
        <strong>_all is an Array</strong><br>
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        <strong>_all is not an Array</strong><br>
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```

Comment: You could use `return is_array($this->arguments['myvar']);`, no need for doing regex magic here.

Answer (score 6):

You have to either create your own ViewHelper, or use the [existing one from EXT:vhs](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Condition/Type/IsArrayViewHelper.html).

It works similar to the `f:if` ViewHelper:

```
<v:condition.type.isArray value="{myvar}">
    <f:then>
        ...
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        ...
    </f:else>
</v:condition.type.isArray>
```

Comment: Then i have to write my own viewhelper i think, i get "your php version is higher than allowed" if i try to install the extension "VHS: Fluid Viewhelpers"

Comment: Which version of TYPO3 are you using?

Comment: Which version of TYPO3 are you using? If 6.2.x, you should not use PHP 7 (it's officially compatible to PHP 5.3.7 up to 5.6), and if 7.6.x, VHS should be available in version 3.0.0, which supports PHP 7.0.x.

Comment: Sorry, SO had some hickups, that doubled the comment.

Comment: I am using Typo3 7.6.9, thanks i will search for v3!

Comment: I need to call it as inline like `<f:if condition="{v:condition.type.isArray(value: myvar, then: 1)}">` if I want to use <f:then> and/or <f:else>